# Facebook preview content appears to not be processing the javascript

Tags: javascript, images, links

When a Facebook user posts a link to the page a preview of the page is displayed. This tends to have the first image from the page. The page I have has one canned image at the top and the rest of the images are specified in javascript code that changes the content of the page. I moved the section with the canned image to the bottom of the page after the dynamic images section. The preview still shows this canned image in the preview.

I am assume somehow Facebook is getting just the original page without the javacript getting the chance to finalize the content. The first 'dynamic' images tend to be the newest content so I would like it/them to come up in the preview rather than the canned one.  What are the options for addressing this issue?

[Original page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200511030115/http://julianlocals.com/alicia/index-org.shtml)

[Modified page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200511015340/http://julianlocals.com/alicia/index-t.shtml)

What is actually happening that is causing this effect?

Comment: Beyond Maximillian's great answer: Retrieving the thumbnail data from a page is a simple task. Adapting that task to process JS is a) too much work, b) a potential security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly control the image Facebook uses by implementing OpenGraph markup on your page. That way, Facebook won't have to "guess" or "pick one" by itself.

Here's a document from Facebook about it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Specifically, you'll need to add the following tag in your page's `head` to specify the web page's poster image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

---

To answer your follow-up question, it's impossible to use JavaScript to change the image that shows up when someone pastes your link into Facebook, as Facebook's crawler does not parse JavaScript.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241258/set-dynamic-meta-tags-and-open-graph-tags-using-jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081004/update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tag-through-javascript

You can, however, [create a share button on your page that shares using a custom image](https://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript). Note that in this case, the image will only be set if the user *clicks your custom share button*. If they *paste the link into Facebook* to share, they will just get the default image.

I am pretty certain that static or server-side opengraph tags are the only way to explicitly set an image when a URL is pasted into Facebook to share.

Comment: I am looking for this image to not be hardcoded. In this case the image URL is fabricated by the javascript.

Comment: @CWHolemanII Please see my updated answer.

Comment: An SSI exec cmd to specify the desired image in the meta tag before sending the page out w/o using the javascript code does the job enough.